# Azure search with Storage table azure

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I'm developing a web project in which I use the Azure search service for searches of records and I use to store Storage table.

I create a index with data and works correctly with the search but when entry new data the service search continues Azure previous records

how you can synchronize records new data from a storage table to azure search? is possible automatic synchronization?

Thanks.

Comment: What platform you are working with? Pure REST APIs, or using SDKs in C#, JAVA, or node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure your indexer has a schedule specified - see [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/search-howto-indexing-azure-tables/) for an example. The data synchronization will occur as per the schedule - it will not happen instantly. The minimal schedule interval is 5 minutes ("PT5M"). HTH!

Comment: Hi Eugene, when I put the type in "azuretable" returns that is not a valid type.

Comment: This returns : "The request is invalid. Details: index : The property 'type' does
not exist on type 'Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2015_02_28.IndexDefinition'. Make sure to only use property names that are
defined by the type."

Comment: Make sure you use the Preview API version: POST https://[service name].search.windows.net/datasources?api-version=2015-02-28-Preview

Comment: Also, you are posting to a wrong URL. POST to /datasources, not /indexes.

Comment: Hi, when I put the script of indexers returns: ""Data source does not contain a required column 'Id'""

Comment: if it was the URL was wrong but now I generates the error when trying to create the indexers "Data source does not contain a required column 'Id'"

Comment: The error message is telling you that in your index, the key field is called 'Id', but there's no such field in the datasource. In the table, we generate a property called Key'. If you can, recreate your index with 'Key' field instead of 'Id'. This is all described in the link I sent you, please take a look.